# How does the photon detector in this experiment work?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, photons, double-slit-experiment, photon-emission

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cg7jMXQHxvM
At 5:46 to 6:37 Dr. Aspect talks about photon detectors. At 6:10 he talks about firing single photons at a time, and having two detectors.

From what I have read, you can't actually detect a photon, only the results of its interactions with electrons. So how do these photon detectors actually work? Is this an EM field detector? Or an electron agitation detector? What are the insides made of, do they detect whenever a photon hits any part inside the detector, or is there some lens that the photon has to hit?

And when a photon is detected, is it destroyed? Or are there mirrors that focus it forwards and it will still hit the screen at the end, forming the accumulating pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single photon avalanche diode detectors (SPAD) are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-photon_avalanche_diode)

> a photo-generated carrier is accelerated by the electric field in the device to a kinetic energy which is enough to overcome the ionisation energy of the bulk material, knocking electrons out of an atom. A large avalanche of current carriers grows exponentially and can be triggered from as few as a single photon-initiated carrier

There is also  the 'Quantum Capacitance Detector' that you could look into.